# Run a package function multiple times with different parameter values

Tags: r

if I have a data frame of historic option data;

```
StrikePrice  UnderlyingPrice Days2Exp RfRate DividendRate Volatility
47           45              4        0.02   0.5          0.2
50           55              20       0.03   0.1          0.35
```

And I am using the package 'LSMonteCarlo' function 'AmerPutLSM';

```
price = AmerPutLSM(Spot = 45, sigma = 0.2, n=500, m=100, Strike = 47, r= 0.02, dr = 0.5, mT = 4)
summary(price)
```

Is there anyway I can do this function without manually having to change the values for the second row in my dataframe? (I'm dealing with a lot of rows in reality)  An example that is wrong but gets the point of what I want to do across;

```
price = AmerPutLSM(Spot = dataframe$StrikePrice[1:2], sigma = dataframe$Volatility[1:2] etc, etc...)
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out `pmap()` from the `purrr` package. You'd do something like `pmap(list(dataframe$StrikePrice, dataframe$Volatility, etc...), ~ AmerPutLSM(Spot = ..1, sigma = ..2, etc...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the apply function here -

```
result <- apply(df, 1, function(x) AmerPutLSM(Spot = x['UnderlyingPrice'], 
          sigma = x['Volatility'], n=500, m=100, Strike = x['StrikePrice'], 
          r = x['RfRate'], dr = x['DividendRate'], mT = x['Days2Exp']))
result
```